# QField fails to start with very simple project

Tags: qgis, android, qfield, qfieldsync

I am new to this software so was following an online tutorial to create a very simple form with an open source base map. QGIS version 3.22.0-Białowieża. QField Sync v. 3.4.4. I copied all the files over to my Android tablet (v. 5.1.1) and when I open the project, QField (v. 1.10.0) just closes. There are no error message, it just states that the software has stopped. The demo projects open ok so QField is working ok. I have taken out the base map in case that is the issue but the project still won't load.

Is it my Android version or something else causing this?

Comment: Can you be more specific. Are you using geppackage, shape files or something else?
Is your form created using the drag and drop designer?
Some screenshots showing how you have set it up at each stage would help.

Comment: Thanks Oisin. I followed the instructions here to create my project:
[https://livelihoods-and-landscapes.com/qgis_qfield_tutorials/training_overview.html](https://livelihoods-and-landscapes.com/qgis_qfield_tutorials/training_overview.html) The instructions created a .gpkg file and I used the drag and drop designer to do so. Interestingly when I go back into the QGIS project now, I can't see all the settings I put in, not sure if that's relevant:
[![screenshot of Drag and Drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNyGO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNyGO.jpg) The QFieldSync Package created 3 files:
[![

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/219135)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: Does your project show labels? You might be using old hardware (arm 32 bit, the android version 5.1.1 is a hint that the tablet is rather old) where there is a bug with labels. https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/777

Answer (score 0):

Is your QGis project a *.qgs project and not *.qgz? [image]

Comment: As of 2023, this information (.qgs incompatibility) is definitely outdated. I am frequently working in QField with .qgz projects, e.g. when working around [this issue](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/2925). Still might be worth a try converting .qgz to .qgs, if you're experiencing issues in QField. However **.qgz** is just a zipped form of the XML-like textfile **.qgs + it's style-database** (which was introduced somewhere around QGIS 3.20, I think).